# Who initiated the "friend" request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-friend-request

Out of my current Facebook friends, how do I check which people added me as a friend and those who friend requested me first?

Is that possible to find out? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question: Who added you as friend, it's easy:

1. Login to your Facebook account.
2. Find the notification image hyper-link (the one with globe symbol).
3. In Notifications, you can check who all added you as friend.

Now for Second Question:
There are two Scenarios:

- If you have already added them as friends then it's not possible to track whether you have added them or they had sent you the request first.
- If the friend request is yet not accepted by you, then you can find it near Home text hyperlink (The image next to Home text Hyperlink, in which two persons are shown).

Answer (score 0):

You can't find out on Facebook for existing friends who sent the request. However, if you have e-mail notifications enabled for friend requests you could search for them among your e-mails and often find "NN confirmed you as friend" (or something like that, the wording has changed during the years) - then it was you who sent the request - or "NN added you as friend" (again, the wording has changed) - then it was NN who sent the request.

For exactly this purpose I have "friend list" called "Friend request" to which I add everyone that sends me a friend request that I accept.